# Suddenly my Tor hidden service isn't available

Tags: help, circuit, onion-routing, client, server

I created a Tor hidden service (a server binded to localhost port and `torrc` config'd to use the 127.0.0.1 xxxx) for clients to connect to. It was working great for a month or so, and now no one can connect to it. I see it is still setup properly in my `torrc`, and restarting `tor` seems to work and it says it's reading from `/etc/torrc`.

Here's my log from the server:

```
Aug 13 10:55:11.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server. 
Aug 13 10:55:11.000 [notice] We now have enough directory information to build circuits. 
Aug 13 10:55:11.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network. 
Aug 13 10:55:11.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop. 
Aug 13 10:55:12.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit. 
Aug 13 10:55:13.000 [notice] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working. 
Aug 13 10:55:13.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done. 
Aug 13 10:56:38.000 [notice] Closing stream for '[scrubbed].onion': hidden service is unavailable (try again later). 
Aug 13 10:56:53.000 [notice] Closing stream for '[scrubbed].onion': hidden service is unavailable (try again later). 
Aug 13 10:57:21.000 [notice] Closing stream for '[scrubbed].onion': hidden service is unavailable (try again later).
```

The client machine `tor` log says the same thing:

```
Closing stream for '[scrubbed].onion': hidden service is unavailable (try again later).
```

On the client end it says the service is unavailable, but on the server end, `tor` is running, and the server process is running.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Can you paste your torrc for the hidden service configuration? What ports is it running on? Can you visit the service from the local machine? 9/10 times this isn't a Tor problem but a host configuration

Comment: the only thing ive modified in my torrc was this: HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/myhiddenservice/
HiddenServicePort 12345 127.0.0.1:12345 and it worked before, for a few weeks. the service is running as a user with sudo priveledges. i also have apache2 running as root on the same machine hosting a website(which was done by the admin a few weeks after i set up my tor hidden service, and seems to be around when the problem started) the service on 12345 is running fine, and it is definitely working properly.

Comment: k got an account. so i have a correction. the root user is just running a nodejs file using port 80, hosting itself.. apache2 isnt running..

Comment: For others landing here - I fixed by changing the system timezone to UTC.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I figured this out. For some reason the custom onion address I made with Shallot was no longer working. I made a new hidden service and got rid of the existing one, restarted Tor, and voila! I'm not sure why this happened, but this solved both hidden services that had stopped working.